# AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE for StaticResource in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-2-rc0

I'm storing all localizable strings in a `ResourceDictionary` (in `App.xaml`) and assign those via the `StaticResource` markup extension to `TextBlock.Text`, `Button.Content` etc.

In Beta 2 and RC0, *sometimes* parsing the XAML in `InitializeComponent()` will fail with an `AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE` on the line and position where I set the attribute value to the `StaticResource`.

It only happens sometimes: When restarting the app, it parses and displays without any problems. The same interface code works for days or weeks, then it happens again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Parser, at least in beta 2, didnt like whitespace...

For instance:

```
Text="{StaticResource bleh}"
```

worked

however this:

```
Text = "{StaticResource bleh}"
```

bombed

Answer (score 0):

Basically it means bad xaml somewhere in the code you can see the Line number and Position and see something is wrong .. I got the same error in my xaml Once corrected everything seems working

Comment: Read the question to the end (by the way, this was two years ago in SL 2.0 Release Candidate): It only happened SOMETIMES. And definitely no bad XAML, I quadruple-checked everything.